# How to set up SPNEGO/KERBEROS in async-http-client?

Tags: java, http, kerberos, spnego

I'm trying to set up the authentication of an `org.asynchttpclient:async-http-client:2.8.1` like this:

```
BoundRequestBuilder requestBuilder = ...;

Realm realm = new Realm.Builder()
                       .setUsePreemptiveAuth(true)
                       .setScheme(AuthScheme.SPNEGO)
                       .build();

requestBuilder.setRealm(realm);
requestBuilder.setHeader("Authorization",
                         "Negotiate " +
                         kerberosTokenCache.get(new URL(baseUrl).getHost()));

Response response = httpClient.executeRequest(request)
                              .get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

On the remote, (to which, unluckily, I have no admin access), some error is occurring which is returing an HTTP 500 response. The admin says it's caused by a failure to authenticate and the remote is simply not responding with a meaningful exception (due to a bug), but that this is the case.

I can see that the token is being sent. I've run `kinit` and when I do `klist`, I can see the tokens.

The JDK (1.8.0_144) has JCE enabled.

Does the code above look correct, or is there more to it? Are there some system properties that need to be enabled?

Comment: You might want to read HTTPCLIENT-1625 and notice that you are of of luck.

Comment: You've confused the libraries. This is not for Apache's httpclient. Either way, I've maanged to solve the issue. AHC was overwriting the `Authorization` header.

Comment: Indeed, but your code is still wrong and violates RFC 7546.

Comment: @Michael-O: Interesting... In what way does it violate it?

Comment: Read the RFC and you will see that you never complete the security context.